# ASP.net: Is there a way to recall data so that when the original data is changed it does not affect the recalled data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Using ASP.net

Users input data in a budget.

When that data is recalled in an estimate, is there a way that if the original data in the budget is changed it does not affect the recalled data in the estimate?

Current solution is to make a copy of the budget data for every estimate. Copy budget never gets changed.

**Budget**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |

**Estimate**
Choose A -> 1
But if I change A to a different value, still want A -> 1 on the recalled data.

Tried described above where budget is copied for every estimate that is created.

Comment: Some code to demonstrate exactly what you are doing and how you are doing it would probably improve your question dramatically. Consider editing your question and adding some additional context. Avoid using images of code unless you are showing something that cannot be reasonable demonstrated without the image. Welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: Need more info. Are you using a database, judging by the table? What do you use to work with the database? Entity Framework? Also tag the programming language.